# Spatial and DateTime join in SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, geography-data-type

I have 2 tables in BQ; one of them includes a geography column **PointWKT (gps POINT)** and second table includes a geography column **BoundaryWKT (POLYGONS & MULTIPOLYGONS)**. Both tables also include DateTime column.

I want to do a spatial join so each PointWKT will be assigned to corresponding BoundaryWKT.
Until today, i was using GeoPandas but now i have to switch to SQL.

**Is there any way in SQL BigQuery that would substitute geopandas .sjoin like:**

```
join_df = gpd.sjoin(table1, table2, how="inner", op='within')
```

**ANSWER** to this question:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE ST_Contains (table1.geom, table2.geom)
```

Another question is, if it is possible to include another condition for joining?

**Besides the spatial join from geography columns i also need to include join on DateTime column from both tables.**

Is this even possible?

Comment: One Question only please, you can ask two separate questions.

Comment: Please do not include answers in the area reserved for your single question.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible, but the performance might vary depending on cardinality of various intersections.

You can include various conditions in `WHERE` clause, including condition on DateTime.

Say you can do something like

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE ST_Contains (table1.geom, table2.geom) 
  AND (table1.datetime BETWEEN DATETIME_SUB(table2.datetime, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
                           AND DATETIME_ADD(table2.datetime, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE))
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! it doesn't exactly solve my problem but you definitely showed a way to go!